# Access first array in javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to access the first array of javascript object

**Date:**

```
      var data = {};
      data['bmw'] = {
        'google':[
          'seller1',
          'seller2',
          'seller3',
        ],
        'microsoft':[
          'seller3',
          'seller4',
          'seller5',
        ],
      };
```

**Output should be:**

```
array(
              'seller1',
              'seller2',
              'seller3',
)
```

**my code (not working)**

```
<script>
    data[Object.keys(data)[0]]; // return Object {item_type1: Array[3], item_type2: Array[3]}

    data[Object.keys(data)[0]][0]; // return undefined
</script>
```

Comment: There are no guaranty of order inside objects.

Comment: You can't have two objects under the same key. You'll only have one 'dynamic_name' array in data object and it will be the second one.

Comment: @jcubic – Can object have multiple key having identical name ?

Comment: If you preparing this response from SERVER then add it to one single key with values as array of array or array like object. your property will overwritten with last element.So u will not get array

Comment: @Maggie I update it now, is it right or wrong ?

Comment: @Rayon I think that the name is just a placeholder for real name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you have two keys with the same name. Its obvious that that the last one will override the first key and you will be able to access the data of the last key. In order to get the data from the first key change the name and then run data[Object.keys(data)[0]] and pass key and value to it. For key 0 you will get the first object and then you can loop inside it to get the values. Updated the answer. Check this.

```
 var data = {};
  data['bmw'] = {
    'google':[
      'seller1',
      'seller2',
      'seller3',
    ],
    'microsoft':[
      'seller3',
      'seller4',
      'seller5',
    ],
  };

 var first = data[Object.keys(data)[0]]; 

 console.log(first[Object.keys(first)[0]]);
```

Comment: awesome awesome :)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
data['dynamic_name']
```

You'll need to access the properties by name.

Comment: data is concated with second array element

Comment: the name is dynamic